# in sql string partial search

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I search Product name with minimum query SQL

```
    id       product-name
    ---------------------
    1        VFD 1.0HP, 3PHASE VFD2A7MS43ANSAA
    2        Cable Flex. PVC 1 core 0.75sq mm Y/G 200m 
    3        Cable Flex. PVC 1 core 0.75sq mm White 200m
    4        Cable Flex. PVC 1 core 0.75sq mm Blue 90m
```

if I do search with Product name for id 3 - `'flex 1 core cable'`.

```
select * 
FROM product 
where product-name like '%flex%1%core%cable%'
```

it does not working properly

if I have search left to right with random word taken---its work properly but if choose word right to left its not fetching data.....
thanks

Comment: *if I do search with Product name for id 3 - `'flex 1 core cable'`.* IDs 2, 3 and 4 matches this criteria.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using different like clauses, so their position won't matter but they'll all be included, example;

```
  select * FROM product where product-name like '%flex%' and product-name like '%1%' and product-name like '%core%' and product-name like '%cable%'
```